# Python Can't Connect to Kernel

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

My Jupyter Notebook will say connecting to kernel before not being able to make a connection.

To correct this I run.

```
python -m pip --proxy http://my_proxy_chain install --upgrade notebook
```

But while installing that, while it's collecting pywinpty>=1.1.0, I get:

```
ERROR: No matching distribution found for maturin<0.13,>=0.12.6
```

What troubleshooting steps should I attempt to get jupyter notebook talking to the kernel? I already installed maturin after getting this error - but that does not change the effect of getting it when I try to upgrade my notebook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try these steps;

create new environment using `venv` or `conda env create -name <YOUR_ENV_NAME>`
install dependancies. (You can even use `pip install -r requirements.txt`
for the jupyter kernel setup;

```
pip3 install jupyter ipykernel
python3 -m ipykernel install --user --name=new_kernel
```

new_kernel is the name of the kernel you need to select in the Jupyter notebook

Comment: Thanks I’ll try this today. Is there any way to get my local machine able to open a notebook without a virtual environment? Or to copy virtual env settings locally?

Comment: You can just execute those commands without creating a new virtual environment (In this case they will be installed in "base" environment). But definitely not recommended as it can clash with whatever packages you have installed in your "base" environment now.

Comment: Thanks. Even after I make a new kernel locally the cmd prompt still gets to "Replacing stale connection:..." and my new kernel remains at "Connecting to Kernel" in the top right of my notebook until it gives up. If possible can I fully wipe my local python dependencies and setup to start from a set of commands that should always have it work?

Comment: Got it sorted. This is what fixed it for me python -m pip --proxy my_proxy install --ignore-install tornado==4.5.3.